# AlmaLinux 8 - /var/log/secure and /var/log/messages stopped updating

Tags: linux, unix, logging, system-administration, almalinux

AlmaLinux 8 on a OpenVZ based VPS. I was trying to set up fail2ban along with firewalld. Maybe it was something I did but was not aware of it, but logs in /var/log/secure and /var/log/messages stopped updating. On one of the forums after searching for a while, I found a thread saying to delete the imjournal.state from /var/lib/rsyslog/, which I did; the logs I had before it stopped logging dissapeared and the ones that are left are from 20 days ago. If you need any logs, other information, info on what I did before, screenshots, I will be happy to deliver them here.

I have restarted the rsyslog but it did not help. Tried different configurations in /etc/rsyslog.conf. Tried to get journalctl and ryslog to work together again, ended up being a failure. Restarted the journalctl service itself. Checked if my logs did exceed the set limit, which they did not. With journalctl --verify found that 2 of my logs were corrupted, to me reason unknown, both only were taking up 3% of the set memory limit.